# What would be the purpose of 'set -e' without any arguments?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a Bash script to control startup order in Docker Compose, similar to the example script given on https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/:

```
#!/bin/bash
# wait-for-postgres.sh

set -e

host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"

until psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\l'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
exec $cmd
```

I'm trying to understand what the purpose is of the first line, `set -e`. The usage from the man page reads

```
set ( -e | --erase ) [SCOPE_OPTIONS] VARIABLE_NAME[INDICES]...
```

Without a `VARIABLE_NAME`, what does this command do? Nothing I guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are referring to. Read `help set`:

> -e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.

Comment: Ah yes, I was looking at `man set` in a different shell (Fish).